# Thymeleaf PDF with Arabic text shows blank

Tags: java, utf-8, itext, thymeleaf, arabic-support

I am using Thymeleaf version `3.1.2.RELEASE` and flying-saucer-pdf version `9.3.1` to generate PDF from a JavaFX application. I have the following `template.html`:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="ar" dir="rtl">
  <body>
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: black">
      <span th:text="${title}"></span>
    </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Method to parse Thymeleaf template:

```java
  private String parseThymeleafTemplate() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("title", "عنوان");

    return templateEngine.process("template", context);
  }
```

Method to generate PDF from HTML:

```java
  public void onPrintPdfButtonClick() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    String outputFolder = ".../template.pdf";
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
    resolver.addFont("src/main/resources/Al Nile.ttc", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    renderer.setDocumentFromString(parseThymeleafTemplate());
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(outputStream);

    outputStream.close();
  }
```

For some reason, the generated PDF file has no content at all! I have set all the file encodings to UTF-8. I am also adding Arabic font to resolver. Nothing works so far. Anyone faced this issued before? I am really interested in understanding the issue, so we can solve it together.

Comment: @KJ You are correct, using ```DejaVuSans.ttf``` and adding ```style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;"``` worked. But the word is not cursive and is shown like this ```ن ا و ن ع```. Any idea about a good and cheap commercial add on that I can use to make Arabic words cursive? Additionally, I added ```lang="ar" dir="rtl"``` to my HTML file in the ```<html>``` tag but it didn't make much of a difference.